# Elementor recent update 3.6, the frontend editing sidebar loader loading continuously

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm using Elementor pro. The website was fine till the Elementor version was 3.5.5. After upgrading the plugin now when I'm trying to edit the page, the Elementor sidebar is loading continuously. As I know Elementor uses many resources, I increased the memory limit. Still, it's loading.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following these step

1. you can disable step by step plugin and check again.
2. Go to admin dashboard -> settings -> permalink and set post name and click save button.
3. Increase memory limit (set memory limit 1024)

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the other plugins.

I encountered the same problem.

The solution is to rollback to 3.5.6

Hope Elementor team can fix this.